# C# WPF INotifyPropertyChanged not updating form

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to implement a form with some calculations based on user inputs.  Using the MVVM pattern, in particular INotifyPropertyChanged.

All works well when the user enters a value in a textbox, the calculation routine fires, and the form updates with the result.

However when the input is changed from codebehind, the Inotify routines fire, the calculation completes, but the bound controls don't update.

I have two problems:

1. Using pages within frames, I want to trigger a refresh when the page is changed
2. Import previously saved data that is in an Xml file. Again, the routine fires, but no update to the form's bound controls.

I have attached a condensed version of the code, but this isn't really the problem I don't think.  Note I am using a singleton class.

Thanks

===============

```
//INotify code
using s = Calc.Models.GlobalStrings;

namespace Calc.ViewModels.INotify
{
    public class UcIOChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private static UcIOChanged instance;
        public UcIOChanged() { }

        //Make the class is a singleton
        public static UcIOChanged Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new UcIOChanged();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Pressure 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return s.Pressure; 
            } 
            set 
            { 
                s.Pressure = value; OnPropertyChanged(); 
            } 
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Pressure)));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help. On the UI element that binds to the Pressure property try the following
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged..
For example <Label Content = {Binding Pressure,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}/>

Comment: As a note, `nameof(Pressure)` should definitely not be inside the OnPropertyChanged method. There should instead be a string parameter, and the method should be called like `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Pressure));`

Comment: What @Saurav says is not correct. `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It controls how the other Binding direction (from target to source) works, and has no effect at all on a OneWay Binding (from source to target only).

Comment: Regarding @Saurav comment, I do have such code in the XML.  Also, when one input property changes, it updates many other bound results, this is not shown in the code example I provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note I am using a singleton class.

There are no errors in this code.
But you may be using it incorrectly.
To avoid accidental usage errors, I advise you to change the implementation:

```
public class UcIOChanged
{
    // Hide the constructor to avoid
    // accidentally creating other instances.
    private UcIOChanged() {}

    //Make the class is a singleton
    public static UcIOChanged Instance { get; } = new UcIOChanged();

    public string Pressure
    {
        get
        {
            return s.Pressure;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(s.Pressure, value))
            {
                s.Pressure = value;
                PressureChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

        }
    }

    // The event of the same name.
    // It's easier for one or two properties
    // than the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation.
    public event EventHandler PressureChanged;
}
```

**Using:**

```
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Pressure, Source={x:Static local:UcIOChanged.Instance}}"/>
```

**P.S.** Correct operation may be affected if you change `s.Pressure` somewhere in your code other than through an instance of UcIOChanged.Instance.
Therefore, you must ensure that this variable (property or field?) is only accessed with notification of its change.

Comment: "*It's easier ... than the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation*" is arguably not true for more than one property, when you could just write `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Pressure)))` instead of `PressureChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)`, but declare only one event instead of one per property. There is no need for the OnPropertyChanged method. Of course you would have to declare the interface implementation.

Comment: I agree.
That is why I have indicated: **"for one or two properties"**.
For more, this is of course pointless.

Comment: Well, for two it's not true :-)

Comment: There is indeed more than one property, more like 30...it is quite a complex calculation.  For example if I change pressure, it will change a gas density, speed of sound etc etc

Comment: Further, there are no actual errors.  If the user updates say the pressure in the form, everything binds, calculates and updates correctly. However if I change the property Pressure, from code behind, the INotify runs as before, calculations update, but the UI doesn't update.  I do have 2 way binding set in the XML.

Comment: The error is not in the implementation of the class.
An accidental error can occur if you have created more than one instance of `UcIOChanged`.
This is exactly what I am showing in my example.
The use of another event is secondary and not important.
This is just additional information.
It is important to HIDE the instance constructor.

If that doesn't help, then we need to figure out how you use this class.
This requires a minimal example of a Solution that reproduces the problem.

Comment: See an example of binding in my answer.
Is that how you write them?

Comment: EldHasp, UcIOChanged is a "singleton" class, there is code at the start of the class to prevent duplicate classes being instantiated.  This is the only way I could get the XML file to update the properties.  I will try your further suggestions provided in the code...thanks for that.

Comment: Your implementation does not have any restrictions on creating other instances.
To do this, the class constructor must be private, as in my example.
In your implementation, it is public and nothing prevents you from creating another instance besides the one in the Instance property.

Comment: My code is, as far as I can tell, functionally the same as EldHasps, except I have grouped all the xChanged.Invokes into a OnPropertyChanged() method, as I wish to update many bindings (eg error status labels, run a calculation, update the results).

Comment: OK, so if I make the constructor private as suggested, that breaks my code elsewhere, so I guess this tells me where I need to look...I thought I had succesfully created a singleton, but now I am not so sure..but at least I have an avenue of investigations.  I will mark this as the answer for now, but I have a different challenge.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, be sure to note that in the logic of your calculations, you should **ALWAYS** access the `s.Pressure` variable only through the `UcIOChanged.Instance` instance.
Wherever you do these calculations.

Comment: Pretty sure this answers it (thank you EldHasp):  I have the singleton re-worked but I can't get the instance to work in XAML?

    <Page.Resources>
        <vm:UcIOChanged
            x:Key="UcIOChangedDataContext">
        </vm:UcIOChanged>
    </Page.Resources>
    
            <WrapPanel
                x:Name="wrpAGA3"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                        DataContext="{StaticResource UcIOChangedDataContext}">

I tried changing   <vm:UcIOChanged  to  <vm:UcIOChanged.Instance but this doesn't work?
Thank you...

Comment: To get an instance in XAML, you must use the x: Static markup extension.
Look carefully in my example how I get the Source in for binding.
It can also be obtained for the data context or for some other property.

Comment: It worked, thumbs up, thanks to all who answered.